# Kendo grid does not refresh when I try to close one grid and open another one in same page on different button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which has buttons in every row, On click the buttons open a pop-up with different grid on each button click, so problem is--

**When I click on any button for first time grid opens with it's related data. When I close that grid and open another grid, I get the same data as previous one**

*When I reload the page and open any grid for 1st time it works fine, If I open a  second one again it repeats*

**What I understood from Network Recording is it is not requesting data from api on 2nd button click and directly using data present in it previously.**

Here is an example of the given problem using local data, can you please help
[Dojo Example.](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/39)

Comment: try refreshing the grid once it opens the second time.

Comment: can you tell how can I do that. I have tried putting one button with reload() class, It doesn't work

Comment: Can you put some code so I can help you?

Comment: Right now it's solved Apollo, Thanks for your concern. can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636158/how-to-assign-datasource-to-detailgridoptionsdataitem